# Email login option gone after FirebaseAuth upgrade iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I suddenly no longer get the email option on the login page. It was always there and then since upgrading it is now gone!

Here is how I declare the providers:

```
   let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
        FUIGoogleAuth(),
        FUIFacebookAuth(),
        FUITwitterAuth(),
        FUIPhoneAuth(authUI:FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!)
    ]
```

I don't see any new EmailAuth. Evidently it was always defaulted in and now it is gone and I can't find any notice of a change.

EDIT:

Tried adding:

```
   let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
        FUIEmailAuthProvider(), <======  compile error
        FUIGoogleAuth(),
        FUIFacebookAuth(),
        FUITwitterAuth(),
        FUIPhoneAuth(authUI:FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!)
    ]
```

but got this error:

'FUIEmailAuthProvider' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

Comment: As far as I can see there were changes to *how* you enable/disable the email sign in in [release 6.0 of FirebaseUI for iOS](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/releases). What version are you using?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 6.1.0... thanks for the link, but now it won't compile

Answer (score 9):

First needed:

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Email'
```

Then added:   FUIEmailAuth(),

Answer (score 4):

What if you replace `FUIEmailAuthProvider()` with`FUIEmailAuth()` instead;

```
let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
  FUIEmailAuth(),
  FUIGoogleAuth(),
  FUIFacebookAuth(),
  FUITwitterAuth(),
  FUIPhoneAuth(authUI: FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()),
]
```

And add the following to the `Podfile:`

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'

pod 'FirebaseUI/Email'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Twitter'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Phone'
```

According to: [Using FirebaseUI for Authentication](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/84007bcff9ebc0f161f794324ca4841e1d8d8492/Auth/README.md#configuration)

Comment: that gives: Use of unresolved identifier 'FUIEmailAuth'; did you mean 'FUIGoogleAuth'?

Comment: yes I posted another comment with it I below. Had to do a pod install first.

Answer (score 2):

Actually its not properly described in the Firebase Documentation for iOS.

You have to add the pod `pod 'FirebaseUI/Email'` and after that:

1. import FirebaseUI
2. include FUIEmailAuth() as a provider

that will trigger Email sign in.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue as well. The following seemed to fix it for me:

1. Add `pod 'FirebaseUI/Email'` to your pod file
2. Make sure that you have the correct import:
   `import 'FirebaseEmailAuthUI'`
3. As mentioned previously, include `FUIEmailAuth()` as a provider:

```
let providers = [
FUIEmailAuth(),
// ..
// ... other providers ...
// ..
]
```